# Current flow in AC vs DC

Tags: ac, dc, grounding

If a live wire is taken from AC and connected to a bulb, while the other terminal of the bulb is connected to ground, the bulb glows; but if I take the positive terminal of a battery (DC source) connect it to one terminal of a bulb, ground the other terminal of the bulb, then the bulb doesn't glow. Why?

(I find this pretty confusing..)

Comment: Mains AC? What sort of battery? Is this the same bulb? What type of bulb?

Comment: Hint : where was the negative of the battery connected? Where was the neutral of the AC supply connected?

Comment: What do you mean by "ground"?

Comment: If you get AC ground from receptacle, eather it is missconnected or there is a serius leakage to ground. Check using a simple electricians screwdriver-checker.

Comment: Yes, Mains AC. A battery means a simple constant dc source. By a bulb I just mean a power dissipation element.@Matt Young

Comment: By ground I mean actual ground, Earth....the floor... :)

Comment: For providing the neutral in case of AC, I connected a wire from the bulb to the floor (ground...or Earth...). In case of DC the negative terminal of battery was not connected to anything.

Answer (score 5):

A battery is not naturally connected to ground/earth on its negative terminal. If it were then you would make a circuit and the bulb would glow (should it compatible with 12V).

AC on the other hand, tends to have its neutral wire grounded at some or several points in the power feed system and this means that a circuit is completed when you ground the bulb.

Comment: I tried the DC part...took a 12 V dc source and connected the positive terminal to one terminal of a 12 V motor. I connected the other terminal of motor and the source to ground. The motor did not run.. :(

Comment: What happened when you connected the DC motor directly across the battery? If it ran then you must have not connected both motor and battery to a ground that was common to both. If the motor still does not run then it's an unrelated problem that only you can fix.

Comment: Yes, it ran when I connected it directly across the battery. I hope you get it that I am using "ground" as ground.

Comment: Then the ground connection you made was not interconnected to both motor and battery.

Comment: I think you do not get it, I am using "ground", "earth", "land" as ground. How do I interconnect the two grounds. I am simply taking the negative terminal and touching it to the floor of my house.

Comment: Is the floor of your house conducting? Ground in electrical terms means a reliable earth connection that has reasonable electrical continuity to other "ground" connections. What you describe does not sound like "ground" so maybe reconsider who has not "got it" LOL

Comment: :P   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29

Comment: It says I can call a physical connection to Earth as ground.

Comment: But ..isn't the ground or earth or floor conducting?

Comment: Floors are almost certainly non-conducting. A ground rod is quite deep and penetrates into that part of the earth that is likely to be conducting.

Comment: But I do get an electric shock when I touch a live wire, standing bare foot on the floor.

Comment: Because your body has capacitance to ground and the power is AC. This forces a few hundred micro amps through your body. This isn't DC - dc won't conduct through capacitance.